# Удаленное управление устройством Android

Tags: android, android-sdk

Стало интересно, как приложение AnyDesk позволяет удаленно управлять андроид устройством?
Есть в Android SDK такие возможности?

Comment: наверно так: сперва видите чужой экран, на своем тыкаете куда-то, вычисляется координата вашего нажатия в рамках того отображения, которое видите, отправляет на удаленное устройство. Там программа делает клик в эту область. А вот какие права нужны чтобы делать клик надо посмотреть